# Move the block showing the question asked on the meta site on the top

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, blocks

In the [front page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/) the block showing some of the question asked in the meta site is sometimes shown on the top, but sometimes it is shown lower.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

At least in the front page, it should be always shown on the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that has been already implemented. The block has been replaced with a different one, that is now always show in a fixed position (at the top of the right side). The block is the "Community Bulletin" one.

[image: screenshot]